# Visual Studio 2015 & .Net Core Tools Update Install Fails

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having an odd problem setting up VSPro2015 on a new laptop running Win7 Enterprise.

The installer is completing but fails to install Azure AD Authentication Connected Service or Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connnected Service - not an imminent problem, I've no present plans to develop against Azure.

However I do have a need to develop against .Net Core, and the installer for .Net Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 is erroring consistently saying VS2015 Update 3 isn't fully installed. From the logs:

```
Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(NetFx45Release < 378675) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR VS2015DevEnvExists OR VS2015WebExpressExists OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR (((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420) OR (VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420) OR (VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420)) OR (VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420)) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015CommunityExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015EnterpriseExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015WebExpressExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists))) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to false.
```

My installed version is reporting as 14.0.25424.00 Update 3. Given that, I think the portion that must be failing is 
(VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion)  AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)
which is puzzling me, as the same update file works on another machine that's reporting the same VS version number.

I've tried repair installs and uninstall / reinstall. I've also tried both the network installer and the ISO image. All of them fail in this way.

Does anyone know how I might be able to get this working so the .Net Core tools will install?

Comment: Same question over on StackOverflow: [Problems installing Dot Net Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tools Preview 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134048/problems-installing-dot-net-core-1-0-0-vs-2015-tools-preview-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not fix the root of the problem (whatever it is), but you can force the installer to skip the version check by using the `SKIP_VSU_CHECK` argument.

eg.:

`DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`

Comment: That's installed, thanks :-) Will leave until I can test more thoroughly before marking as the accepted answer just in case, but I've got further than before!